# Gamma transition between states with same spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, nuclear-physics

So one of the basic selection rules for nuclear transitions is for initial and final spins $I_i$ and $I_f$ that the possible values of *L* of the emitted photon are $|I_i - I_f| \le L \le |I_i + I_f|$.

However in a recent lab I undertook, we investigated Barium-133 which has a 79.6 keV transition from a state at 160.6 keV and angular momentum of 5/2+ and 81.0 keV and 5/2+. Surely this transition is forbidden and cannot occur?

Comment: Why do you say it is forbidden?

Answer (score 1):

First of all each transition can be mediated by one or more terms of the [multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion). For each term (electric dipole E1, magnetic dipole M1, electric quadrupole E2, etc.) you have some [selection rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule#Summary_table) that relates the initial to the final state, indicating the allowed transitions.
For your specific case take a look at the image below [[Reference](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~ianrit/gammaspec.pdf)].
[image: Ba133]
Focusing on the transition of interest ($5/2^+\to5/2^+$), you see that it is labeled with M1+E2. Indeed, checking the selection rules for these two (see previous link), you have that both satisfy
$$
\Delta J=0\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\pi_f=\pi_i,
$$
which is exactly what you need in order to make the transition possible.

Answer (score 1):

Transitions where $J$ changes from zero to zero are forbidden, because the photon must carry away at least one unit of angular momentum.

However if $J\neq 0$, transitions which preserve $J$ are allowed.  The angular momentum carried away by the photon goes into changing the projection of $J$ onto your favorite axis --- that is, $J_z$ changes --- but the total angular momentum is conserved in all reference frames.  Working this out is a nice QM problem.